# How to generate a matrix as follows?

Tags: python, numpy

So given number `n` and an array `a`, we need to create a `n` by `len(a)` matrix where the `i,j`th entry of the matrix is `1` if `i` equals to `j`th entry of `a` and `-1` otherwise. Namely for each numbers `i` from `0` to `n-1`, we need to have an array that tell us if the  number `i` is equal to the array `a`.

It would be cool if we had map feature like in functional programming. Then I could just create the rows by checking for each elements in array `a` if that element equals the given number or not.

So is there a feature that I can use as shown below?

```
result=[]
for i in range(n):
    result=np.vstack(result, np.map(checkequals(x,i),a)
return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a functional or mapping approach is not optimal with `numpy`.  `numpy` is all about arrays, so it's best to think in terms of the whole-array building blocks that `numpy` provides.  Those operate in compiled code.

For example with your case:

Define an array:

```
In [10]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,9)                                          
In [11]: a                                                                      
Out[11]: array([6, 0, 2, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 1])
```

Compare it with the range of `n` values - using whole array `==` test (and `broadcasting`.  The result is a boolean array, a True/False value for each (i,j):

```
In [12]: np.arange(8)[:,None]==a                                                
Out[12]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Given that, it's easy to map it onto a (-1,1) values.  `np.where` is just one such way:

```
In [13]: np.where(np.arange(8)[:,None]==a, 1, -1)                               
Out[13]: 
array([[-1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

Closer to your map idea, we could define a function that operates on a pair of scalar values:

```
def foo(i,x):
    if i==x:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

and use `np.vectorize` to make a function that takes 2 arrays, and passes pairs of scalars to this function.

```
In [16]: np.vectorize(foo)(np.arange(8)[:,None], a)                              
Out[16]: 
array([[-1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

But this is MUCH slower than the first approach.

A list comprehension approach:

```
In [22]: [[(1 if i==x else -1) for x in a] for i in range(8)]                   
Out[22]: 
[[-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1],
 [-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
```

which can then be made into an array (this may actually be faster than the `vectorize` approach).

Answer (score 0):

Python2 has a built in [map function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), and so does [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). Numpy has [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)